# Событие window.onbeforeunload на js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код

```
function closeWindow() {
 i = window.event;
if(window.event.target.activeElement.type !== 'submit') {
     $.get('/site/index?type=delete').success(function(data){

     });
     $.get('/site/index?type=clear');
  }else{
      $.get('/site/index?type=clear');
  } 
 }

window.onbeforeunload = closeWindow;
```

Принцип действия такой - прежде чем юзер уйдет со страницы должны отработать два запроса на сервер, нужно дождаться пока метод seccess вернет ответ и только после этого происходил уход со страницы.  Сейчас запросы не успевают отрабатывать и страница просто перезагружается. seTtimeout не подходит так как неизвестно сколько ждать времени ответа от сервера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Принцип действия такой - прежде чем юзер уйдет со страницы должны отработать два запроса на сервер, нужно дождаться пока метод seccess вернет ответ и только после этого происходил уход со страницы.

Боюсь что это невозможно. Там весь код должен быть синхронным, никакие таймауты  после ухода со страницы ожидаться не будут. Если повезёт, то короткий таймаут может успеть сработать до закрытия.

Так что посылай запрос, а ответ на него ждать бесполезно. Можно попробовать послать синхронный запрос, но я сомневаюсь, что это поможет, поскольку браузер не станет вечно ждать скрипт.

Comment: Как раз синхронный я и попробовал и получилось, страница грузится чуть больше обычного но зато без сбоев. Я вполне могу заставить браузер подождать управляя событием onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

Включите в $.get функцию-колбек, которая исполнится по окончании запроса.

```
$.get( "/site/index?type=clear", function( data ) {
  alert( "Ура, загрузилось!" );
});
```

Comment: я понимаю но как это реализовать для моего примера?

Comment: Где в вашем "примере" команда закрытия окна? window.close или что там? Вот ее и вставьте ровно туда, где у меня в примере alert()

Comment: Проблема в том что если я засуну windowclose вместо alert то окно перезагрузится и все. window.onbeforeunload - должен быть глобально, что-бы перехватывать событие ухода со страници

Comment: Я вас не понимаю и сдаюсь.