# window.onbeforeunload кроссбраузерная обработка

Tags: javascript, события

Данный вопрос возникает с регулярной периодичностью, взять хотя бы [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433047/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-window-onbeforeunload-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js)

Я так же столкнулся с этой проблемой и мне так же необходимо выполнить POST-запрос при закрытии вкладки/браузера.

Для себя я определил 2 решения:

1. в **window.onbeforeunload = function() {}** в конец пихаем **return 'Вы действительно хотите выйти?';**. В данном случае return корректно обрабатывается во всех браузерах и выводит диалоговое окно.

Тут можно будет уповать на то, что пока пользователь донесёт курсор и нажмет на подтверждение закрытия, POST запрос успеет отправиться.

2. В onbeforeunload пихнуть открытие нового небольшого окошка, в которое передать необходимые параметры для запроса, выполнить его и после выполнения закрыть только что созданное окно

**"За" и "против":**

первый вариант неудобен тем, что пользователь может нажать "не показывать всплывающие сообщения" и все диалоговые окна в этой вкладке умрут, а значит у меня ничего не будет выполняться, пока не будет открыта новая вкладка. Так же, если пользователь выберет "остаться на странице", то POST-запрос всё равно отправится.

Второй вариант мне не нравится тем, что все браузеры блокируют всплывающие окна, а значит нужно будет добавлять исключения в настройках браузера.

Кто что может посоветовать? Решение должно быть кроссбраузерными, но только для десктопных версий браузеров. Каков из двух вариантов является более предпочтительным и чаще всего используется?

P.S. полезные ссылки:

[Раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973816/why-is-jquery-unload-not-working-in-chrome-and-safari), [Два](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload), [Три](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794301/window-onunload-is-not-working-properly-in-chrome-browser-can-any-one-help-me/9909822#9909822)

P.P.S.
Насколько я понял, onbeforeunload вообще не является частью стандарта, а является рекомендацией. Изначально его придумали для ИЕ (не удивительно, что там у меня всё работает), но вроде как все браузеры всё равно поддерживают эти события. Главным условием для выполнения того, что написано в обработчике для этих событий, является то, чтобы код был синхронным, тогда как GET/POST запросы асинхронны. Можно конечно включить синхронность, но, например, с Chrome такой финт не пройдёт, так как такой подход является deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данную проблему можно решить несколькими способами, знаю 2 из них:

1. Можно воспользоваться [navigator.setBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)
2. Можно сделать пустой цикл на секунду в момент когда срабатывает слушатель *beforeunload* тем самым притормозить момент закрытия браузера для того что бы post запрос успел отправиться

Пример пустого цикла:

```
canst oldTime = (new Date()).getTime() + 1000;
while((new Date()).getTime() < oldTime){}
```